# React DnD : Dynamic accept types : When a type is dropped, limit the target to this type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dnd

I hope someone can help me with that.
I have multiple types defined in a useDrop hook, if one type is dropped, I want to limit the next drops to this type.
After the first drop, I know the filtered type but it seems that the useDrop doesn't take the change in the accept type and still accept the default list.

Reproduction

https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-shtern-guxdw?file=/src/Dustbin.jsx

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. Go to codeSandbox
2. Drag and drop BOX type

Expected behavior
You should be able now to drop only BOX type and not BOX2

https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/issues/2862

Answer (score 0):

"a workaround would be to use a key property equal to your accepted types on the component which contains your drop target. This would ensure that it re-mounts once you change the acceptable type(s)"

https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/issues/2732#issuecomment-677739822